# Blender Bones: How to Join Bones with Objects

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

My ultimate goal is to have a arm that can move in Unity.  I have made an arm in blender and have added bones to that arm.

How do I connect the bones to the arm?  Is there an easy shortcut to do this?

Comment: Since you're asking about blender side of things, and not Unity, I think that your question is better suited for this site: http://blender.stackexchange.com/